# NFS won't export /etc or /var (!?)

Tags: linux, fedora, nfs, export, unix-utils

This is on Fedora Server 35, BUT, I'm pretty sure that's irrelevant:

I have a whole environment that works great with nfs and various machines export to each other - been doing this for decades - and we decided that exporting /etc and /var between two systems that are critical and one is the backup system for the other was a good idea to help synchronization. (That is, ease backup for failure recovery a little so it could be done "by hand" more quickly when changes are made - OBVIOUSLY one wouldn't want to rsync the tree!)

Fine... Copy a line in exports that's already there and working fine between the machines twice and change the exported locations to /var and /etc respectively.

Simple, right? Doesn't work!

So, there are REALLY two questions here:

1. Is there some built-in reason why NFS refuses to export these directories? No error is returned, it just doesn't export them. And no, that's not just the commands executed, and yes, I checked the system log.
2. If in fact there IS some limitation like this, what's a good workaround? ... I seem to recall that NFS won't follow sym links on exports, but maybe I'm wrong about that; I tried it some time back and it didn't work.

Comment: By "doesn't export" do you mean `exportfs` ignores the lines or do you mean `mount` is denied access to them?

Comment: @user1686 The former, however, not JUST exportfs, I've also tried reloading the nfs-server.service, and I KNOW it's responding to changes because I have changed other exports from rw to ro and I see the changes in /var/lib/nfs/etab. As for mount, it just says: "mount.nfs: mounting 192.168.1.1:/etc failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory" And, of course, both /var and /etc exist!